# When to use which: Static Resources VS Asset Files

Tags: files, static-resources, asset

Static Resources and Asset Files seem to serve same purposes to me because they both can be used for coding, branding, and design.

What are the differences between these two? What are the best practices to use them?

[**Static Resources**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pages_static_resources.htm&type=5)

> Static resources allow you to upload content that you can reference in a Visualforce page, including archives (such as .zip and .jar files), images, style sheets, JavaScript, and other files. Static resources can be used only within your Salesforce org, so you can’t host content here for other apps or websites.

[**Asset Files**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_files_asset_files.htm&type=5)

> Asset files are packageable versions of Salesforce files that are used for branding and design purposes in your org or Experience Cloud site. Asset files can be used for headers and logo images. They can also be referenced by components. You don’t need to create asset files for regular, collaborative use of Salesforce Files.